# Vestal Versions -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, vestal-versions

I'm using the Vestal Version Fork here for Rails 3 support: http://github.com/adamcooper/vestal_versions/

The issue I'm having is that the updated_by => current_user is not storing in the versions table on update.

```
def update 
        @book = Book.find(params[:id]) 
  respond_to do |format| 
    if @book.update_attributes(params[:book].merge(:updated_by => current_user)) 
      format.html { redirect_to(@book, :notice => 'Book was 
successfully updated.') } 
      format.xml  { head :ok } 
    else 
      format.html { render :action => "edit" } 
      format.xml  { render :xml => @book.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity } 
    end 
  end 
end
```

I checked the logs, there is no error, Rails is INSERTING NULLs in the DB for the user fields, the one I need to populate is user_id

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: i suppose it goes without saying that you are in fact logged in when running this code?

Comment: Good question :) Yes I am, current_user is being used in other methods in the controller to get to the point where I can update book

Comment: Any progress on this? I am experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: I was never able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your model class should make it work

```
attr_accessible  :updated_by
```